# Read and Write Data into Python Files

Tags: python

Please advise how I'm getting the following error:

```
File "/Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/OOP/csv_write.py", line 8
  print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code:

```python
import csv

with open('employee_birthday.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'\t{row[0]} works in the {row[1]} department, and was born in {row[2]}.')
            line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

As I'm trying to read from the file and display the information as follows as per [the link](https://realpython.com/python-csv/).

employee_birthday.txt :

```
name,department,birthday month
John Smith,Accounting,November
Erica Meyers,IT,March
```

This question has been resolved and thank you for the responses below.

Comment: show and example for the data

Comment: Please update your question with the full text of your code and full error traceback.

Comment: Thanks, this is the code and sample data checked into the Git repository and it worked as suggested by @FishingCode:
https://github.com/eugenesheyko/csv_write/blob/master/csv_write.py#L13

Appreciate if you can also advise how to print the 'line_count' variable and the names of the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for that line the traceback is referring to:

f-strings apply for py3.5 and greater versions, see if either of these work:

```
print('Column names are',", ".join(row))
```

OR

```
print('Column names are %s'%", ".join(row))
```

OR

```
print('Column names are {}'.format(", ".join(row)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to update the print statements as follows:
https://github.com/eugenesheyko/csv_write/blob/master/csv_write.py

Comment: "*f-strings apply for py3.5*" It was [introduced in Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), not 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using `Python >= 3.6` as [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) were introduced later. If that still doesn't work, check the indentation for the code.